# Selects products from sub category Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to display all products from certain sub -category when I click on link. I'm kind of new in Laravel and I'm not sure what is happen here as is say `TokenMismatchException`. This particular version is 4.2.

This is my view link

```
<a href="{{ URL::to( '/admin/subCategory/products/' .  $subcategory->sub_cat_id) }}">Subs</a>
```

This is route

```
Route::get ('/admin/subCategory/products/{subcatId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@quickEdit', 'before' => 'csrf|admin']);
```

And the controller

```
public function quickEdit($subcatId)
{       
    $subcatProducts = SubCategories::with('products')->findOrFail($subcatId);
    return View::make('site.admin.quick_sub_cat_products', [
        'subcatProducts' => $subcatProducts
    ]);        
}
```

Pretty easy task yet this is what I get in error log

> TokenMismatchException

Comment: Is the route protected with CSRF token middleware?

Comment: Well I think yes, because it must be logged in the admin. But I'm logged in and from one admin link I'm trying to open another. All other links are working normally

Comment: CSRF protection is not just for not-logged-in-users. It's about pretecting endpoint from being manipulated by other websites making call to yours. An example for you might be an image tag on another site like this: `<img src="https://yoursite.com//admin/subCategory/products/1" />` [Try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/7af015qn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel throw TokenmismatchExceptio because you mention **csrf** in before clouse in route.

```
Route::get ('/admin/subCategory/products/{subcatId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@quickEdit', 'before' => 'csrf|admin']);
```

try to remove csrf from it.

will you try this one ? clear browser cookies from beginning. and just test you link and also do this one. chmod 777 ./storage/framework/sessions

Comment: All other links and href's are the same and they are working. Why this is different?

Comment: when you clicks on this link user loged in to system or not ?

Comment: It is logged. It's admin user. Admin is logged and on page Sub Category and clicks on some sub-category name to view the products under this sub-category. Both pages are using `csrf|admin`

Comment: are open link in new tab ? or there may be different csrf_token set in session ? so laravel can't execute your link and throw tokenmismatchexception.

Comment: It is simple link. No new tab ( you can see in the question ). How can I check if is different csrt_token on second page and why will be changed by itself?

Comment: will you try this one ? clear browser cookies from beginning. and just test you link

and also do this one. chmod 777 ./storage/framework/sessions

Comment: Well clearing the cookies helps. I don't understand why. When I log in it's store the session and cookie. Why they are different?

Comment: it may be system got stuck, multiple session when page reload quickly multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the route in web middleware , as all the routes mentioned in this middleware require csrf token .
Change the route to

```
Route::get ('/admin/subCategory/products/{subcatId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@quickEdit']);
```

Comment: Like this even non-logged in user can access the page.

Comment: You can add separate middleware to check logged in users. something like RedirectIfNotAuthenticated